# Updating Kendo on ASP.NET MVC 5 Stackoverflow exeption

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I'm getting a Stackoverflow exeption after updating my ASP.NET MVC Project to the latest Version of Kendo UI. Tested with R3 2020 and R2 2020, the previous Version which worked was R2 2018. I have checked the .NET and ASP.NET Version on the Server.

Error Log  Failure on the Server:

```
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll 
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899b8a
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.4240.0, time stamp: 0x5f20f681
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00000000000223a7
Faulting process id: 0x4ca8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6a11e84fe56c3
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 28b73723-692f-4040-94cc-272234ac2a6d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same type of error. It took me quite a while to find the issue:
The problem in my case was, that I had a dynamic variable where I called the .ToString() function inside my kendo grid column ClientTemplate:

```
.ClientTemplate("Some html string" + ViewBag.SomeObject.ID.ToString() + "End of html string")
```

I solved the problem by creating a variable of type int and forced the type onto the variable:

```
@{
    var id = (int)ViewBag.SomeObject.ID;
}
```

and then I changed my ClientTemplate to:

```
.ClientTemplate("Some html string" + id.ToString() + "End of html string")
```